# Specifying SCM (cvs/svn) executables when executing job on a Jenkins slave node

Tags: jenkins

I can see how you can specify "Tool Locations" on a Jenkins slave node for things like Java/Ant etc.  However, I can't see how you can specify the location of SCM tools like Subversion or CVS on the slave box?

My job runs on the slave node but is assuming that cvs exists in the same location, which is just not the case.

Thanks Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to specify the location of cvs/svn in the slave configuration. However, there is an easy way around that:

- On your slave configuration page, add an "Environment Variable"
- Set the name to PATH
- Set the value to **$PATH:/path/to/folder-containing-cvs**

This should add cvs to the path and allow Jenkins to use it.

I would also suggest doing this for the master, instead of specifying the exact location of the executables in "Configure System" - this allows for more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks @Sagar, this would most likely work if our master wasn't configured to use a specific local CVS.  It uses that location however you've configured the slave.  Probably a bug in Jenkins

Comment: Well, not necessarily a bug, although the option to change it would be good (you could file a bug @ their JIRA). I think they assume that you would place the executable in the same place on all computers. In your case, on your master, instead of specifying the exact location, just point your PATH to the same folder where it is. This allows for different locations for master and slave. This would still let you use the specific local CVS you need to.

Comment: Please note that code for accessing subversion is included in the subversion plugin directly, so you don't need to install it separatedely, but you also cannot exchange it with a newer version. E.g. there are some problems with Version 1.7 repositories/working copies in the current version of Jenkins.

Comment: I've just hit the same problem and not quite sure I understand the suggested workaround - should 'path/to/folder-containing-cvs' be the full executable path (including P4.exe for example) and then the config for each job should have nothing in the executable path field, or should it just be to the directory containing P4.exe and the job config just have 'P4.exe' in the path to executable? Neither seem to work for me.

Comment: It should be only the path to the directory containing your executable. In your example, it should NOT contain P4.exe